# Remove elements from XML whose contents match a any of a few words

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have this:

```
string1 = "<det>This</det> <vbz>is</vbz> <det>a</det> <nn>text</nn> <in>that</in> <vbz>has</vbz> <det>some</det> <vbn>desired</vbn> <nn>text</nn> <to>to</to> <vb>be</vb> <vbn>found</vbn>" 
substring = "desired text"
```

I need to get something like:

```
ary = [
  "<det>This</det>", "<vbz>is</vbz>", "<det>a</det>", "<in>that</in>",
  "<vbz>has</vbz>", "<det>some</det>", "<to>to</to>", "<vb>be</vb>",
  "<vbn>found</vbn>"
]
```

I know I can do it with some regex and arrays/hashes and nested loops.
I wonder though if I can use Nokogiri to somehow introduce some elegance into this process?

Comment: So you want to *remove* elements from the xml if any match any term from the substring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is an XML document fragment, so you can use Nokogiri on it like so:

```
require "nokogiri"
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(string1)
```

To get a list of all elements that do *not* match words from your substring, do this:

```
words = substring.split
doc.xpath('*').reject {|e| words.include? e.text}.map(&:to_s)

#=> ["<det>This</det>", "<vbz>is</vbz>", "<det>a</det>", "<in>that</in>", "<vbz>has</vbz>", "<det>some</det>", "<to>to</to>", "<vb>be</vb>", "<vbn>found</vbn>"]
```

This matches the output you want.

Comment: Note that if you just want the words themselves, swap `map(&:text)` for `map(&:to_s)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could permanently remove these elements from your fragment with `words.each{ |word| doc.xpath(".//*[.='#{word}']").remove }`...but since we're in Ruby, it makes sense to revel in our own language and not necessarily use heavy XPath. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `split` command, which is [built into Ruby's String class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split).  You could use it like so:

```
string1 = "<det>This</det> <vbz>is</vbz> <det>a</det> <nn>text</nn> <in>that</in> <vbz>has</vbz> <det>some</det> <vbn>desired</vbn> <nn>text</nn> <to>to</to> <vb>be</vb> <vbn>found</vbn>"
ary = string1.split
```

Then you can loop through the array with the Array class's [`map` function](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map).  I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do though?  Get the index of the value in the array?  If that's the case you can use the Array class's [`index` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-index) like so:

```
ary.index(substring)
```

Comment: substring does not have tags, which elements of ary in this case will contain - the substring is a text without <> tags..